# Dom4j Detach/Copy node from one xml and add to another

Tags: java, dom4j

I am actually traversing `src` xml and converting it into another `destination` xml. But part of `src` xml will be just copied and added to the `destination`. But when I am trying to do that I am getting following **Exception:**

```
could not be added to the element "<DestinationParent>" because: The Node already has an existing parent of "<SourceParent"
```

I am traversing src XML and calling this function
**Code**

```
private static Element treeWalk (Element rootElement, Element parentElement)
{
    Element moduleRootElement = doc.addElement("Request");
    if(rootElement.getName()=="someName")
    {
        moduleRootElement.add(childElement.getName());
    } else {
        moduleRootElement.add(rootElement); //If root's parent is not null I get a exception here.
        //moduleRootElement= rootElement.createCopy(); //Didn't work
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more details. Like sample code, input and output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call `detach()` on the node you want to move.  From the [dom4j JavaDocs](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/index.html)

```
Node node = ...; 
Element someOtherElement = ...; 
someOtherElement.add( node.detach() );
```

Since `Element` implements `Node` if you need to convert back to `Element` you can do it just by casting (provided you know that the thing you detached was an `Element`).  Another option for you might be to copy the `Element`.  Using your code as a starting point:

```
Element moduleRootElement = doc.addElement("Request");
if (rootElement.getName().equals("someName") {
    moduleRootElement.add(childElement.getName());
} else {
    moduleRootElement.add(rootElement.createCopy());
}
```

It looks like you actually tried this, but didn't quite get all the way there.  Remember, in java using `=` reassigns the variable to the new object.  All the existing references to it are broken.

As a side note, you probably also need to check your root element's name with

```
if(rootElement.getName().equals("someName"))
```

instead of using `==`

Comment: How can I convert node to Element? If not how to create a new `someOtherElement`?

Comment: `Element` implements `Node`